Multivariate Analysis for Personal Hygiene Product Survey
I conducted a survey involving 5 different personal hygiene products. Each product had 6 different brands, and participants were asked to select one or more brands they preferred for each product. In addition to brand preferences, I collected sociodemographic data from the participants, such as age, income, and other relevant characteristics.
Survey Details:

Products: 5 different personal hygiene products
Brands: 6 brands for each product
Selection: Participants could choose more than one brand per product (multiple choice responses)
Additional Data: Sociodemographic characteristics (age, income, etc.). I'm planning to include these sociodemographic variables in my analysis to understand the relationships and patterns better.

My Questions:

Multivariate Analysis: Given the nature of my data, would a multivariate analysis be appropriate? If so, which specific type would you recommend?

Resources: Could you suggest any books, studies, or articles that explain how to conduct this analysis effectively, especially for multiple choice responses?



What is your research question?

@whuber  Thank you for your reply. Here are my research questions:
How does the impact of sales promotion affect the purchasing choices of respondents aged 18 to 50?
How does the purchasing behavior of respondents vary with and without discounts on selected products?
What are the key variables influencing the purchasing decisions of respondents?
What is the estimated effect of sales promotions on the purchasing decisions of respondents?

What is the variation in the marketing, discount, and promotions variables across users, products, and brands? When a consumer chooses multiple products, how is that represented in the data: with ranks or just binary flags?

@dimitriy  Thanks for your reply. In my study, I use binary flags to represent consumer choices when they select multiple products. Each product chosen by a consumer is indicated with a '1', while products not chosen are indicated with a '0'. This approach allows me to analyze which products consumers prefer during promotional periods and how these preferences vary across different marketing, discount, and promotion variables.

But how are users and brands assigned to a particulat discount? You need some variation, ideally random, to detect an effect. If everyone in the data sees 20% off the whole time, then it's hard to learn anything.

@dimitriy sorry, I didn't specify, in my survey, there were two distinct periods. In the first period, no discounts were applied. In the second period, discounts of 20% were applied to products from three specific brands. This methodology aimed to analyze the impact of discounts on purchasing decisions. While the discounts were consistent across the selected brands, the variation in purchasing decisions between the periods without and with discounts was the focus of measurement.

Is there any overlap in responders between the two periods?

@dimitriy My study tracked the same group of respondents across both periods to observe changes in purchasing behavior with and without discounts.

This is a tricky quant marketing problem with multiple complications. I am not aware of an easy solution. But I will try to outline how I think about the problem to point you in the right direction.
There are discrete choice models where people choose one alternative from several: the one that gives them the highest utility. There are also ranked-choice models, where people rank some or all the alternatives, possibly with ties and variation in how many items in each choice set a person ranks. This allows you to model a setting where people can pick multiple items. Your survey has the complication that people can take home more than one item, but you don’t know how they rank the ones they took home, making it harder to back out parameters like price sensitivity.
One possible solution is to redefine your choice set to fit into the discrete choice framework. To make a set of alternatives mutually exclusive, you can consider choosing multiple alternatives as a separate alternative. For example, with one or more choices allowed from alternatives A, B, and C, the set of alternatives is A only, B only, C only, A
and B, A and C, and B and C, and A+B+C, for a total of seven alternatives (assuming you have to pick something). When there are only a few alternatives, this may be an appropriate way to model your data. You have six brands in a category, so that means $2^6-1=63$ possibilities. This will create computational difficulties since there are a lot of parameters, but it could be doable if there are some restrictions on basket size.
You have alternative-specific variables (like price) and case-specific variables (demographics). You will need a model that can handle both types.
You will probably have to model each product category separately in its own model. This is problematic if there are interesting cross-product effects: if you lower the price of deodorant, someone might buy less body spray. Separate product models preclude this.
Since you have panel data, you will have to handle the fact that the two observations for the same user at different times are not independent. This will require clustering your standard errors by user or using a discrete choice model that can accommodate panel data.
Possible DC models to consider:

Conditional logit (McFadden’s) choice model
Mixed logit choice model
Multinomial probit choice model
Panel-data mixed logit choice model

